# SQL reading numbers formatted "000 that is less than 100

Tags: sql, ms-access, format

I created a rookie Access program and use the following SQL to drill down my selections.  The equipment numbers range from 000 - 5000.  Everything works like I expect for numbers greater than 099 however my search results will not drill down to equipment numbers less than 100.  If I change `((TBTask.EquipID) Like "*" &[Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchEquipment] & "*")` to `((TBTask.EquipID)Like [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchEquipment])` I can drill down to it but then I loose the capability to drill down WO numbers.  I know the problem is the leading "0" when number is 99  but I cant figure out how to work around it to achieve both results and leave the tables in tack.

```
SELECT TBEquipment.[Equipment No], TBEquipment.[Equipment Name], TBTask.*
FROM TBEquipment INNER JOIN TBTask ON TBEquipment.[Equipment No] = TBTask.EquipID
WHERE (((TBTask.CLOSED) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchClosed] & "*" Or (TBTask.CLOSED) Is Null) 
AND ((TBTask.EquipID) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchEquipment] & "*") 
AND ((TBTask.ID) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchWO] & "*") 
AND ((TBTask.Opened) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchOpened] & "*") 
AND (((TBTask.Description) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchKeyword1] & "*" Or (TBTask.Description) Is Null) 
And ((TBTask.Description) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchKeyword2] & "*" Or (TBTask.Description) Is Null) 
And ((TBTask.Description) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchKeyword3] & "*" Or (TBTask.Description) Is Null) 
And ((TBTask.Description) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchKeyword4] & "*" Or (TBTask.Description) Is Null)) 
AND (((TBTask.Solution) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchKeyword5] & "*" Or (TBTask.Solution) Is Null) 
And ((TBTask.Solution) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchKeyword6] & "*" Or (TBTask.Solution) Is Null) 
And ((TBTask.Solution) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchKeyword7] & "*" Or (TBTask.Solution) Is Null) 
And ((TBTask.Solution) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchKeyword8] & "*" Or (TBTask.Solution) Is Null)) 
AND ((TBTask.PartsToOrder) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchParts] & "*" Or (TBTask.PartsToOrder) Is Null) 
AND ((TBTask.PartsRequest) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchPartsRequested] & "*") 
AND ((TBTask.PartsComplete) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchPartsOrdered] & "*") 
AND ((TBTask.Review) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchReview] & "*") 
AND ((TBTask.SafteyIssue) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchSafety] & "*") 
AND ((TBTask.Mgr_Approved) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchMgrAP] & "*") 
AND ((TBTask.Status) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchStatus] & "*")) 
OR (((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchWO],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchEquipment],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchOpened],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchClosed],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchKeyword1],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchKeyword2],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchKeyword3],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchKeyword4],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchKeyword5],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchKeyword6],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchKeyword7],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchKeyword8],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchParts],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchPartsRequested],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchPartsOrdered],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchReview],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchSafety],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchMgrAP],""))="") 
AND ((Nz([Forms]![Search]![SearchStatus],""))=""))

ORDER BY TBTask.CLOSED DESC;
```

Edit: fixed formatting

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL is product specific.)

Comment: Simplify! Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: Access 365, " SQL statement in MS Access 365".  So my problem is when I  try to drill down WO's that start with 0  or 00 I get no results.  If i drill down WO's 100 or greater everything seems to be ok.  Looks like I have a problem including the leading zeros in my statement.  Working on example

Comment: Example A) Results when I query 000 using "((TBTask.EquipID) Like [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchEquipment])"
ID EquipID  Description
400 000  Text 0a
401 000  Text 0b
406 101  Text 101a
-
Example B) Results when I query 000 using "((TBTask.EquipID) Like "*" &  [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchEquipment] & "*")"
ID EquipID  Description
400 000  Text 0a
401 000  Text 0b
-
Referring to the org SQL statement and Example B I can  drill it down but when I then try  a 2nd part of my search "((TBTask.ID) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchWO] & "*")" without selecting the related EquipmentNo I get nothing

Comment: sounds like the real issue is storing numbers as strings and when sorting he is getting weird behavior

Comment: Edit question to show sample data instead of a comment.

Comment: I get the problem is due to a conversion because the difference in achieving results using Like *""* and Like "". I just cant figure out how to format the likes to achieve both. 

TBEquipment "Equipment No" , Integer ,Format:000
TBTask "EquipID" Integer

Comment: Even if it worked you'd end up returning data you don't want e.g. "98" would bring back 298, 498 etc. Sounds more like a design issue to me ; either have the input be numeric and cast relevant DB strings to numbers (then use "=" instead of "LIKE"), or have everything as character and prompt the user to input four digits NNNN

Answer (score 0):

[SQL reading numbers formatted "000 that is less than 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091421/sql-reading-numbers-formatted-000-that-is-less-than-100)

I think the problem arises from automatic type conversion taking place: your code is using a "099" (string) and a "99" (string coming from the number 99), and both are considered as being different. Most likely the string "099" (and similar ones) becomes the number 99 at some point of the expressions, because Access and VBA silently perform type conversion.

To solve this, you can convert all these type of information to numbers using the function CDbl(), unless you want "0" to be different from "00" and "000". An alternative solution is that you make sure that he strings are not automatically converted to a number at some point: you can use the funcion Cstr() to make sure that the string variables do not become numbers.
More information in [lightningguide.net](https://lightningguide.net).

Comment: thanks,  that actually works but I found the root of my problem was I used a wild card in the string.  Problem is fixed by

Comment: Thanks,  that actually worked as a backup plan,  but I found I could get result I wanted by droping the wild card in my sql string because "SearchWO" was married to "SearchEquipment" .

Changed from:
AND ((TBTask.EquipID) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchEquipment] & "*") 
AND ((TBTask.ID) Like "*" & [Forms]![SEARCH]![SearchWO] & "*") 

Changed to:
AND ((TBTask.EquipID) Like Forms![Search].SearchEquipment OR Forms![Search].SearchEquipment IS NULL) 
AND ((TBTask.ID) Like Forms![Search].SearchWO OR Forms![Search].SearchWO IS NULL)